# Python unittest: setUpClass(), tearDownClass(), setUpModule() and tearDownModule() are not called

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

With the `unittest` module using python 2.6.6, how to invoke code after all tests have run ?

Please considere the following MCVE:

```
#!/bin/env python
import unittest

def setUpModule():
    print 'setUpModule'

def tearDownModule():
    print 'tearDownModule'

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print 'setUpClass'

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print 'tearDownClass'

    def test_trivia(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

def main():
    """entry point"""
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would expect to see `tearDownClass` and `tearDownModule` to appear on the console, but it does not:

```
$ ./test.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The class and module setup functions were added in Python 3.2.

Comment: @MarkTolonen After thorough inspection, it seams that `*Class()` methods are supported since python-2.7 and `*Module()` since python-3. Thank you.

Comment: You're right about `*Class()` in 2.7, but I read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html?highlight=setupclass#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass).  On further inspection it was new in 2.7 *and* 3.2.  3.0 and 3.1 did not have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer for Python 2.6:

The [Python 2.6 unittest doc](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) does not mention setUpClass, tearDownClass, setUpModule and tearDownModule methods/functions. So they are probably not supported by unittest and not called at all.

**However**, [unittest2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) seems to support Python since 2.4. It may brings you features that unittest for Python 2.6 does not support.

---

## Answer for Python 2.7 or higher:

I think you are not doing anything wrong and the setUp* and tearDown* functions/methods are called. I think that unittest is just hidding the printed strings.

Try to provide verbosity level 2 to your call to [unittest.main](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) function, it should fix the "problem":

```
unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: it seams that `unittest.main()` on python 2.6 does not accept `verbosity` argument: "unittest.main(verbosity=2)\nTypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbosity'"

Comment: @YSC: I did not note that you were using Python 2.6 :/ Unfortunately, since the 2.6 unittest doc does not mention `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` methods, I think it is simply not supported...

Comment: Just saw that (btw I'm not the downvoter, I'll compensate). There's nothing said about `setUpModule()` and `tearDownModule()`, do you know since when it is supported?

Comment: @YSC: there is no mention of it in the 2.6 doc, but no "since" clause in the python 2.7 doc. I assume it came with Python 2.7 but I am not sure.

Comment: @YSC: done. give a look at the "However" part of my edit, you could be interested in giving a look at unittest2

Comment: FYI, `*Class()` was new in 2.7 and 3.2.  3.0 and 3.1 didn't have it.